# how to generate curves of different curvature connceting 0 and 1?

Tags: r, distribution, curve

I know this is mores statistical than programming question, but I would like a solution in R if possible. How can I generate a set of concave and convex curves of different curvature connecting 0 and 1 as shown in the example below:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `pbeta` to plot the CDF of the beta distribution for different shape parameters

```
shape1 <- c(4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
shape2 <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4)
x <- seq(0, 1, length.out = 100)

library(tidyverse)
map2_dfc(shape1, shape2, ~pbeta(x, .x, .y)) %>%
    bind_cols(x = x) %>%
    gather(key, y, -x) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x, y, group = key)) +
    geom_line()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

They look like powers of x. The ones above the 1:1 line are powers < 1 and the ones above are powers > 1. So you want y = x ^ n where n > 0. There are other families of curves you could use as well.

```r
x <- seq(0, 1, 0.01)
ns <- c(0.1,0.11,0.13,0.15,0.17,0.2,0.25,0.33,0.5,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
plot(x, x, type = "l")
for (n in ns){
    lines(x, x^n)
}
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: many thanks! I think the pbeta distribution looks a bit more symmetrical around the 0.5 point, but this is also very useful!

Comment: This is probably the simplest. Beta is certainly beautiful.

Comment: but perhaps a little too clean, looking at your example figure... so you might even want to interpolate between beta and power, to get curves that aren't as symmetrical as beta, but also not as biased as power curves.